# SASS Compilation works, but Gulp doesn't

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, gulp

I'm just starting out with Gulp but I can't seem to get it working. When I just run the regular sass command everything compiles just fine.

Here is my Gulp file:

```
//Gulp Dependencies
var gulp = require("gulp");
var log = require("fancy-log");

//Style Dependencies
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var scss = require("gulp-sass");
var autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
var cssnano = require("gulp-cssnano");

function scssTask() {
    return gulp.src(["../css/partial/*.scss",
        "../css/*.scss","])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .on("end", function(){ 
            log("Sourcemap Complete...");
        })
        .pipe(scss())
        .on("end", function(){ 
            log("SASS Compiled...");
        })
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .on("end", function(){ 
            log("Autoprefixer Done...");
        })
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .on("end", function(){ 
            log("CSS Minified...");
        })
        .pipe(gulp.dest("../../dist/css")
        )
        .on("end", function(){ 
            log("SCSS Task Complete!");
        });
}

exports.default = gulp.series(scssTask);
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
[05:12:57] Using gulpfile /path/to/gulpfile
[05:12:57] Starting 'default'...
[05:12:57] Starting 'scssTask'...
[05:12:57] 'scssTask' errored after 26 ms
[05:12:57] Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:
    ../css/coming-soon.scss
Error: no mixin named background
        on line 4 of ../css/coming-soon.scss
>>   @include background($images + "blurground.jpg");
   -----------^

Details:
    status: 1
    file: /var/www/pickle.codes/src/css/coming-soon.scss
    line: 4
    column: 12
    formatted: Error: no mixin named background
        on line 4 of ../css/coming-soon.scss
>>   @include background($images + "blurground.jpg");
   -----------^

    messageFormatted: ../css/coming-soon.scss
Error: no mixin named background
        on line 4 of ../css/coming-soon.scss
>>   @include background($images + "blurground.jpg");
   -----------^

    messageOriginal: no mixin named background
    relativePath: ../css/coming-soon.scss
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
```

Here is the relevant part of coming-soon.scss

```
@use "partial/base.scss" as *;

html {
  @include background($images + "image.jpg");
}
...
```

and here is the relevant part of _base.scss

```
$images: "/static/images/" !default;

@mixin background($background-image-path) {
  background: url($background-image-path) center center fixed;
}
```

Other people who had an issue similar say they hadn't named their partial scss file with an "_" however that is not my case as "_base.scss" does --in fact-- have an underscore. My next thought was that since the regular sass command was working that it must be because Gulp wasn't compiling _bass.scss before coming-soon.scss, so I moved _base.scss to it's own folder and put that new "partial" folder first in the array. But that didn't seem to help.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if it ends up being I just fudged a semi-colon or something :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your `_base.scss` file imported into your `main.scss` file? Gulp can't find your mixin. To make sure your partials are imported in the proper order, I'd recommend using a `main.scss` file and gulping over that file.

For a great sass boilerplate based on the 7-1 architecture pattern: https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/sass-boilerplate

More specifically the `main.scss` file: 
https://github.com/HugoGiraudel/sass-boilerplate/blob/master/stylesheets/main.scss

Comment: Yep, that was the issue: Gulp didn't seem to like `@use`! 
I was trying to stay away from `@import` in favor of `@use` because the SASS site warned against it: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import but I'd rather cross that bridge when I get to it and be able to use Gulp. Do you know of anyway I could get Gulp working with `@use`?

Either way thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't, I use @import as of today  Next time I use gulp, I'll try a different packages to compile sass and let you know if one works. Just re-tried with the last web app I used gulp on using `gulp-sass` and `@use` didn't work either. It compiled to `@use 'abstracts/variables';`!

Comment: As I dive deeper into this I'm getting the idea SASS is trying to get people on board with some not-so-great ideas. I ran into another issue because the site encouraged me to use `@extend` but upon further research I learned it wasn't a great idea (Another article by the very talented Hugo Giraudel :D) :
https://www.sitepoint.com/avoid-sass-extend/  and also
https://pressupinc.com/blog/2014/11/dont-overextend-yourself-in-sass/

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I'll read both =) Yeah I think it's best to follow what works best on a per project basis. Recommended best practices (not only for SASS) are not always the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

The `background` mixin cannot be found because the Sass compiler you're using doesn't support the `@use` directive and so isn't including your `_base.scss` file where the mixin is defined.

Currently gulp-sass uses sass-node as its default compiler. sass-node is a binding for LibSass, [which is deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated) and was never updated to support the `@use` directive.

You can set gulp-sass to instead use the primary implementation of Sass, [Dart Sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass). Dart Sass supports `@use` and other recent features of Sass.

Install Dart Sass as a development dependency for the active project:

```sh
$ npm install dart-sass --save-dev
```

Then within your gulpfile you can set it as the compiler to be used by gulp-sass:

```js
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const dartSass = require("dart-sass");
    
sass.compiler = dartSass;
```

There are some [compatibility differences](https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Compatibility+-+P1+%E2%9A%A0%EF%B8%8F%22) between LibSass and Dart Sass to be mindful of if you're swapping compilers on an existing project.